# delete recording sqlite3 with flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am trying to configure flask view to delete recording from a sqlite3 database  table but I get some errors, please see below what I have coded so could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
@app.route('/delete/<int:entry_id>')
def delete_entry(entry_id):
   con = sql.connect("database.db")
   con.row_factory = sql.Row
   cur = con.cursor()
   entry_id=int(entry_id)
   cur.execute("delete from students where id=?", (entry_id,))
   con.commit()
   rows = cur.fetchone();
   return redirect("http://192.168.1.1:4000/list")
```

.

```
<a href="{{ url_for('delete_entry', entry_id=row['id'] )}}">Delete</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly after the `execute` call, you need to also call `commit`:

```
cur.execute("delete from students where id=?", (id,) )
cur.commit()
```

Edit: you have to create a function parameter to correspond to the value being passed to the route, with the same name:

```
def delete_entry(entry_id):
  pass
```

Comment: Is not working.. I am receiving : File "/home/petrisor/python/app.py", line 86, in delbut
cur.execute("delete from students where id=?", (id,) )
InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @Slashlinux what is `id` storing?

Comment: id is from the database

Comment: @Slashlinux Yes, however, what is the type of `id`? An `int`, a `tuple`, a `list`? It is a possibility that `id` is actually a single tuple directly from your last `fetchall()`

Comment: here is my entire code : http://194.135.89.2/app.txt    id is a integer, 
sqlite> .schem
CREATE TABLE students(
id int primary key not null,
name text not null,
addr text not null,
city text not null,
pin text not null);

Comment: @Slashlinux I am not sure what the type of `id` is supposed to be in the database, but when you access `id` from `request.form`, the type will be a string. Therefore, I suggest you cast `id` to an int `cur.execute("delete from students where id=?", (int(id),) )`

Comment: I did that: **cur.execute("delete from students where id=?", (int(id),) )**  but I have an error: **TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'**

Comment: @Slashlinux `id` is a built in function to find the address of a value in memory. It appears that from the error you posted and you code, `id` is not declared in the scope of the function with the delete route. You need to store a value for a variable named `id` in the function for the delete route.

Comment: I have modified the above code from the post but I have another error: **TypeError: delete_entry() takes no arguments (1 given)**

Comment: I did that.. nothing is working, the same error : ** TypeError: delete_entry() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given) **

Comment: I found the answer, I've have modified in the code above, is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I solved adding `()`after the `id=  cur.execute("delete from students where id=(?)", (id,) )`
just in case another had the same issue try adding those `()`
this was working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different but achieves the same result:

```py
@app.route('/delete/<id>')
def delete_entry(id):
    entry = MyDatabase.query.get(id)
    db.session.delete(entry)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('lists'))
```

The delete link will be:

```py
<p><a href=" {{ url_for('delete_entry', id=entry.id) }} ">Delete</a></p>
```